# Define record start ID

Tags: plugin-development, records

Is there a way to define my plugins Record start ID? Now it start with ID 1, and for various reasons I would like to define a starting number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most direct way, but you could do something like this from your plugin's record:

```
public function createTable()
{
    // Let the base class do the actual work
    parent::createTable();

    // Change the PK auto-increment starting point.
    craft()->db->createCommand()->setText('ALTER TABLE myTable AUTO_INCREMENT=9999')->execute();

}
```